# Internal resistance of a battery

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

It is my understanding that internal resistance of the battery is mainly due to resistance of its electrodes and electrolytes. During the charge or discharge of the battery, there's a potential drop $\Delta V$ due to its internal resistance $R$. We know that $\Delta V = EMF - RI$ and it is due to charge separation on the electrodes.

I am trying to conceptualize the electric fields in the battery. I believe that the electric field across the battery due to charge separation has dropped, and this loss is equal to the electric field associated with $RI$.  Can somebody confirm whether my understanding is correct - or clarify where I went wrong if it is not?

Comment: I am sorry for this issue but I am just asking about the theory (I don't know if it is true or not because I couldn't find it on the internet). How can I ask this question in another way:p. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You are not asking about theory. Your question is "can we say...". That is a yes/no question. I will try to do a suggested edit to your question.